How to write a custom select Command for a table adapter created at runtime code
I have a certain section of code where I create a table adapter for an existing binding source/ dataset at runtime when I click into that function or section.
Short code example here.
            Dim P4_Num1_TA As name_DSTableAdapters.P4_Num1TableAdapter
            P4_Num1_TA = New name_DSTableAdapters.P4_Num1TableAdapter
            Pick4_DB.name_BS.DataMember = "P4_Num1"
            P4_Num1_TA.Fill(DBname.name_DS.P4_Num1)

You get the idea.
I'm trying now to use an sql query to call just one record to edit at a time.
I created a string variable for my sql command text which is fine. But this line here gives the IDE a headache.
P4_Num2_TA.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = SQL_SelCmdText
Error msg says this ...
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.get returned Nothing.
So I'm thinking ... Since my table adapter is created at runtime, it aslo needs to have a New Select Command
declared as well but I haven't been able to figure that one out yet.
Anyone got any ideas ???
Tried lots of different permutations and combinations based on how I created my table adapters at runtime.
Wasn't expecting much
